# Quanteda's corpus_reshape function: how not to break sentences after abbreviations (like "e.g.")

Tags: r, quanteda

I am using Quanteda (v. 2.0.9000) for text analysis in R (v. 4.0.0).

I use the `corpus_reshape` function to split my texts into sentences, but I have noticed that the function not only break documents at the end the sentence, but also when there is an abbreviation with a dot (such as "e.g.", "i.e.", "U.S.") is followed by a capital letter or a digit.

Is there any way to prevent these particular splits? A way to tell the function: "do split texts, but not when the characters before the dots are "e.g", "i.e", "u.s"?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Without an example of the problem, I cannot solve it, but on my system, it works fine.

```r
library("quanteda")
## Package version: 2.1.0

txt <- c(
  d1 = "This is an example, e.g. something.  Whatever, i.e. something.",
  d2 = "The U.S. is south of Canada."
)
corpus(txt) %>%
  corpus_reshape(to = "sentences")
## Corpus consisting of 3 documents.
## d1.1 :
## "This is an example, e.g. something."
## 
## d1.2 :
## "Whatever, i.e. something."
## 
## d2.1 :
## "The U.S. is south of Canada."
```