# How can you exclude certain words before periods from being used as sentence breaks in quanteda's corpus_reshape?

Tags: r, corpus, quanteda, sentence

In some cases, certain periods are mistakenly used as sentence breaks when using `corpus_reshape`. I have a corpus from the pharmaceutical industry and in many cases "Dr." is mistakenly used as a sentence break.
This post ([Quanteda's corpus_reshape function: how not to break sentences after abbreviations (like "e.g.")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62691994/quantedas-corpus-reshape-function-how-not-to-break-sentences-after-abbreviatio)) is similar but does unfortunately solve the problem. Here is an example:

```
    library("quanteda")
    
    txt <- c(
      d1 = "With us we have Dr. Smith. We are not sure... where we stand.",
      d2 = "The U.S. is south of Canada."
    )
    corpus(txt) %>%
      corpus_reshape(to = "sentences")
```

> Corpus consisting of 4 documents.
> d1.1 :
> "With us we have Dr."
>
> d1.2 :
> "Smith."
>
> d1.3 :
> "We are not sure... where we stand."
>
> d2.1 :
> "The U.S. is south of Canada."

It works only for few cases with "Dr.". I was wondering if certain words to be excluded can be added to the function because I would like to avoid using an alternative function to break the text into sentences. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use `corpus_segment` with `pattern` & `valuetype = "regex"`.

You may find example here

https://quanteda.io/reference/corpus_segment.html

You may also use `use_docvars` option.

Comment: That worked, thanks. Here is the function and the regex I used if others have a similar problem: corpus_segment(corpus, pattern = "(?<!(Dr|Mr|Mrs|Ms|\\s|\\s[[:alpha:]]|\\.\\.|[[:alpha:]]\\.[[:alpha:]]))[.!?](?=\\s[[:upper:]])", valuetype = "regex", use_docvars = TRUE, pattern_position = "after", extract_pattern = FALSE)